# Find line that does not end in 83 consecutive commas

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a large csv file that I'm searching using Notepad ++.

Looking for a regex (or other method) to find a line that does not end with 83 consecutive commas.

I'm thinking something like this:

`[^,]{83}$`

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: Tried that and got 0 matches... but I'm not confident that `[^,]{83}$` is what I want. Is that saying find 83 not-commas then end of line?

Comment: "Is that saying find 83 not-commas then end of line?" Yes, it is.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what you've mentioned in the question title.

Comment: Does not end in 83 consecutive commas is not the same as end with 83 consecutive non-commas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with `[^,]{83}` is that it requires there to be 83 characters which at the same time none are commas. So if any of the last 83 characters are a comma then that expression will fail. It would be easier to use a negative lookahead to search for the bad thing and and fail if is found.

```
^(?!.*,{83}$)
```

[image]

Comment: AFAIK notepad doesn't support look-arounds

Comment: @Bohemian: Current versions do.

Comment: If you have access to the latest version of Notepad++, use this solution.

Comment: +1 for answer, but especially for effort to create screenshot :)

Answer (score 1):

You're searching for 83 *non* commas at the end of a line, but some may be commas.

Use a look-behind anchored at the end-of-line to assert that the previous 83 characters are not *all* comma (*some* are allowed to be, but not *all*):

```
(?<!,{83})$
```

Comment: Also works although is drastically slower than @Denomales answer.

Answer (score 0):

So you want (start-of-line or a non-comma character), followed by not-more-than-82 commas.

```
(^|[^,]),{,82}
```

Answer (score 0):

Denomales is right, but I'd go with this:

`([^,],\{0,82\}|^,{0,82})$`

It matches a line that ends in a non-comma character followed by anywhere between 0 and 82 commas, or a whole line of less than 83 commas.

Comment: Isn't that second alternative included in the first? Also, you might have to supply the `0` in the quantifier explicitly... I'm not entirely sure about Notepad++'s regex flavor right now, but most flavor's do not accept the first number being omitted.

Comment: You're absolutely right. It was a mistake for me to post without testing. I've updated my response to be more accurate.